# “Access violation reading location 0x000000000” in a simple OpenGL app

Tags: c, opengl

I have a problem in openGL when using buffer object to store vertex array .
when I run the code , a window appears that display  message " *access violation reading location 0x000000000* " and when I move the cursor to arrow beside glGenBuufers function I see description: *this is the next statement to execute when this thread returns from current function*.

[image: IDE snapshot]

Code:

```
int frame=0;
void display();
void datasource();

 GLuint vbo;

void datasource()
{
    GLfloat vertex1[]={-1.000000 ,0.500000 ,-0.700000 ,0.500000 ,-1.000000 ,0.800000 ,-0.700000 ,0.800000 ,-0.400000 ,0.500000 ,-0.100000 ,0.500000 ,-0.400000 ,0.800000 ,-0.100000 ,0.200000 ,0.500000 ,0.500000 ,0.500000 ,0.200000 ,0.800000 ,0.500000,0.800000 ,0.800000 ,0.800000 ,0.500000 ,1.100000 ,0.500000 ,0.800000 ,0.800000 ,1.100000,0.800000  };

    glGenBuffers(1,&vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(vertex1),vertex1,GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}


void init(int arc,char **arch)
{
    glutInit(&arc,arch);
    glutInitWindowSize(800,800);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutCreateWindow("chess");
    glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
}

int main(int arc,char **arch)
{
    init(arc,arch);
    datasource();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}

void display()
{
    frame++;
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,0,8);
    glutSwapBuffers();
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: SO is not for code review. Please ask a concrete technical question.

Comment: I don't see where you initialise vbo before you pass its address to glGenBuffers

Comment: Does he have to initialize it? The second argument to `glGenBuffers` is an array of `GLuint`s to store the created buffers. If there’s just one buffer, passing an address of a single `GLuint` should do?

Comment: He’s not asking for code review (“is this code good?”), he’s asking for help with a reasonably concrete problem (“why does this short code sample segfault?”). Seems fairly on-topic to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assist me to understand OpenGL glGenBuffers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102864/assist-me-to-understand-opengl-glgenbuffers)

Comment: This question is perfectly valid. His program crashes, because he uses functions not available through the system default ABI and need to be post-loaded into the process after OpenGL initialization. *Could people who do know understand how OpenGL works please stop from trying to answer these questions – I got the feeling there's a trend ATM that people value on OpenGL questions only because they have a hunch.* Yes, the problem is a FAQ, yes it creeps up every week or so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

glGenBuffers, glBindBuffer and glBufferData are functions of either the Vertex Buffer Object *extension* or of OpenGL-1.5. The default system ABIs only go to OpenGL-1.2 so you need to post-load extended OpenGL functionality before you can use it. Just including the headers is not sufficient, because those just provide you the uninitialized symbols.

Most easy way to go:

1. Download and install GLEW from http://glew.sf.net
2. Replace all occurances of `#include <GL/gl.h>` with `#include <GL/glew.h>`
3. Call `glewInit()` right after `glutCreateWindow` and check the error code
4. Check if are VBOs are available (i.e. at least GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object or OpenGL version >= 1.5)
5. Add the GLEW library to your linker settings

Answer (score 2):

It’s possible that the function pointer itself (`glGenBuffers`) is `NULL` ([source](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/170104-glGenBuffers-segfault)). This happens when the OpenGL system wasn’t properly initialized yet, and calling a `NULL` function pointer will obviously cause a segfault. Take a look at the address of `glGenBuffers`, is it `NULL`? If yes, then you’re making a mistake somewhere in the initialization code.

Comment: Problem is, OP didn't initialize extendend OpenGL functions at all. The standard system ABIs for OpenGL go no further than OpenGL-1.1 (Windows) or OpenGL-1.2 (GLX).

Comment: you right , glGenBuffer was null because I did not invoke the `glewInit` function , thank you