# OpenGL - Exception at clear Color

Tags: c++, exception, opengl

I'm trying to open a window using glfw3, and paint the background blue. Here's my code:

```
#include <glad\glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
GLFWwindow* window;
int main( void )
{
    int windowWidth = 1024;
    int windowHeight = 768;
    glfwInit();  
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    window = glfwCreateWindow( 1024, 768, "Tutorial 14 - Render To Texture", NULL, NULL);

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &windowWidth, &windowHeight);
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);

    glfwPollEvents();
    // Dark blue background
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);
    return 0;
}
```

At glClearColor, it throws

```
Unhandled exception at 0x74D2CB49 in rendertotexture.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000.
```

I already tried 
[GLFW exception on glClearColor and glClear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45118349/glfw-exception-on-glclearcolor-and-glclear).
I'm using Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: [`gladLoadGL()`](https://github.com/Dav1dde/glad)

Comment: "I already tried [GLFW exception on glClearColor and glClear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45118349/glfw-exception-on-glclearcolor-and-glclear)."...then where's your `gladLoadGL()`/`gladLoadGLLoader()` call?

Comment: I removed it, when it didn't make a difference

Comment: @QStollen: Did you call it after `glfwMakeContextCurrent` – it needs a OpenGL context bound to the current thread, in order to work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize glew and call glfwSwapBuffers(window).

See: https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/window.html

> GLFW windows are always double buffered. That means that you have two rendering buffers; a front buffer and a back buffer. The front buffer is the one being displayed and the back buffer the one you render to.
>
> When the entire frame has been rendered, it is time to swap the back
>   and the front buffers in order to display what has been rendered and
>   begin rendering a new frame. This is done with glfwSwapBuffers.

```
int main(void)
 {
    GLFWwindow* window;

    int windowWidth = 1024;
    int windowHeight = 768;
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    window = glfwCreateWindow(1024, 768, "Tutorial 14 - Render To Texture", NULL, NULL);

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glewExperimental = true; // Needed in core profile
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
    }

    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &windowWidth, &windowHeight);
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
       glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
       glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);
       glfwSwapBuffers(window);
       glfwPollEvents();
    }

    return 0;
}
```